# Execute calc.exe in html

Tags: angular

I am trying execute calc.exe in my html

```
 <button onclick="window.open('file:\\\C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe')">
   Open
 </button>

 <a href = "C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe"> go </a>
```

But I can't this.

I see "ActiveX" but this is only for IE, I need launch calc.exe in Chrome,IE,Mozilla with "Angular6" or JS Or Jquery, how can I do this ? thanks.

Comment: Not possible. Exe's can never be run via the web.

Comment: You can use electron to communicate with OS programs. The browser won't allow you.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not do that as that would be a huge security breach that would allow websites to execute commands on your OS level.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use electron or you write your own solution. With own solution I mean a local server application in any language, which receive web requests (wss, rest...) and executes commands on your machine.